# How to get mat-tree-node element from drop event in the mat-tree in Angular2+?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-material2

I have a requirement where I need to implement drag and drop between two containers which have a tree-like structure. One container is TODO, the Other is Done. It's working but dropped data always getting attach to node 1 of the Container 2(Done) because I don't know how to find the dropped container node index?

[image]

Here is code. Working demo can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tree-with-drag-and-drop-cf8aka?embed=1)

```
import './polyfills';

import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {DemoMaterialModule} from './material-module';

import {TreeFlatOverviewExample} from './app/tree-flat-overview-example';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [TreeFlatOverviewExample],
  declarations: [TreeFlatOverviewExample],
  bootstrap: [TreeFlatOverviewExample],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Drag "Other" and drop into "Done" container now open Node 1. you will be able to see the dropped element.

**Requirement**: I want to drag from TODO container and want to drop into the exact Node of the container 2. 
Quick help will be really appreciated.

Comment: So If I dragged `Security` on `Node 2`, then is should get appended to Node 2, right?

Comment: @Plochie correct

Comment: @Plochie How are you thinking to do it if the Container 2 Nodes are dynamically creating which are coming from the API? I also think the same to have multiple drop zone node but getting stuck due to data source property which is required for mat-tree. In case of dynamic nodes list not sure how to do it. Also creating multiple data sources can cause performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Finally after some research I am able to achieve the requirement by using "div" and "**cdkDropListGroup**" property which connects multiple drop zone.

According to angular `If you have an unknown number of connected drop lists, you can use the cdkDropListGroup directive to set up the connection automatically. Note that any new cdkDropList that is added under a group will be connected to all other lists automatically`

In the drop container, I can not use mat-tree because that requires a data-source property that can not be dynamically defined(As of now I am aware of). whereas in my case I wanted multiple drop zones dynamically, So I used "**div**"

Below is the working link, if someone requires this kind of implementation then refer to the below link. I hope this will save someone time.

[drag-n-drop-treelist](https://mat-tree-with-drag-and-drop-h6ghkd.stackblitz.io/)

[image]

Comment: you should accept this answer, so that the question gets concluded.