# Angular: Drag and Drop - Fill [cdkDropListConnectedTo] dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk-drag-drop

Drag and drop should be possible as follows.

- You can move items from container 1 to containers 2, 3 or 4.
- You are not allowed to move items from container 2, 3 or 4 to container 1.
- items from containers 2 to 4 can be moved back and forth.

[image]

I'm just missing **[cdkDropListConnectedTo]**

How do i have to populate **[cdkDropListConnectedTo]** to meet my needs?

Redundant code should be avoided as much as possible.

This is my current code.

```js
<div *ngFor="let book of this.books; let i = index">
    <div>
        <div
            cdkDropList
            id="book-container-{{i}}"
            #ref{{i}}="cdkDropList"
            [cdkDropListData]="book.getDropListData()"
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]= "[]"
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <div>
                <p class="headline">{{book.getHeadline()}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53250585/4472932

Comment: @Flo I'm still not clear how to dynamically implement cdkDropListConnectedTo with no redundant code that meets my needs.

Comment: cdkDropListEnterPredicate is your friend. See my answer with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example. You can move from container one to container two. But not back from two to one.

**Here is the solution for the html part:**

Use the `cdkDropListEnterPredicate`attribute. This fires if any item over the other container. Here is the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#DropListRef).

```
<div
  cdkDropList
  id="two"
  [cdkDropListData]="basket"
  class="example-list"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
  [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="canDrop">
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of basket" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

**The code behind:**

Here we check the id of the item.dropContainer (the start container it was nested) and the list.id (the target container you wanna drop). Simple if you move from two -> one return false.

```
  canDrop(item: CdkDrag, list: CdkDropList) {
    console.log(item.dropContainer.id, list.id);

    if (item.dropContainer.id === 'two' && list.id === 'one') return false;
    return true;
  }
```

Try it all [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ui7u9m-u32fua?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-disabled-sorting-example.html) in Stackblitz!